# Is this the proper way to not create in each class a new PDO object in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to use in my application PDO connection within multiple classes (objects) but the way how I tried in the past was not correct because everytime I called an object I created a new PDO object (connection) also.

Im right now using a spl_autoload_register for autoloading.

Here Is my DataBase class (I deleted from this example the connection propeties (name, host etc etc.):

***DataBase.php***

```
namespace MyApp;

use PDO;

class DataBase {
    
    public function DB_CONN() {
        try {
            $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->DB_name, $this->DB_username, $this->DB_passw, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            // Set the PDO error mode to exception
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example here I need a PDO connection to ***Customer*** class and I created a PDO object in the Customer constructor like this:

***Customer.php***

```
namespace MyApp;
use MyApp\DataBase;
use PDO;

class Customer 
{
  private $PDO;

  public function __construct($cus_id)
  {
    $this->PDO = (new DataBase)->DB_CONN();
  }

  public function getCustomerOrders(int $id): array
  {
    $CustomerOrders = (new Orders())->getOrdersByID($id)
  }

  public function getCustomerNameByID(int $id): ?string
  {
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute([":id" => $id]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result["name"];
  }
}
```

But its not the best method because because if I need an another class in this example named ***Orders*** (which also needs a DataBase connection) then I will create an another PDO object.

***Orders.php***

```
namespace MyApp;
use MyApp\DataBase;
use PDO;
class Orders
{
  private $PDO;
  public function __construct($cus_id)
  {
    $this->PDO = (new DataBase)->DB_CONN();
  }

  public function getOrdersByID(int $id): array
  {
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id =:id");
    $stmt->execute([":id" => $id]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
 }
```

So my question is that should I only pass the $PDO variable to the given class constructor? It will solve my problem? Like this:

```
try {
    $pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . $db_host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $db_username, $db_passw, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
    return false;
}

class Customer
{
    private $PDO;

    public function __construct(\PDO$PDO)
    {
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }

    public function getCustomerOrders(int $id)
    {
        $CustomerOrders = (new Orders($this->PDO))->getOrdersByID($id);
    }

    public function getCustomerNameByID(int $id): ?string
    {
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute([":id" => $id]);
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result["name"];
    }
}

class Orders
{

    private $PDO;

    public function __construct(\PDO$PDO)
    {
        $this->PDO = $PDO;
    }

    public function getOrdersByID(): array
    {
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE ID =:id");
        $stmt->execute([":id" => $id]);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

$Customer = new Customer($pdo);

print_r($Customer->getCustomerNameByID());
print_r($Customer->getCustomerOrders());
```

Or should I use dependency injection? Thank you!

Comment: your last example is along the lines of the Dependency Injection pattern, which is commonly used these days to solve this kind of issue and related problems. It's considered a good approach to this kind of thing.

Comment: Please remove that useless try-catch. Never catch exceptions if you have no intention of recovering from them. Do not die with an error message as this exposes your credentials to the world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I only pass the $PDO variable to the given class constructor ... or should I use dependency injection?

That *is* dependency injection.

It's tempting to think of Dependency Injection as a complex technical concept, which needs an entire framework to implement, but in reality it's just a *way of designing code* and can be summed up very simply:

> "dependencies" (things the class needs) should be "injected" (passed in from outside)

Having a constructor which expects a database connection follows this principle perfectly.

The reason frameworks often provide specific functionality under the umbrella of "Dependency Injection" is that as your code gets more complex, you end up with a web of objects which need to be passed into each other's constructors, so you have to create them in the right order, and keep track of which ones are already constructed. A "Dependency Injection container" is just a way of managing all these objects: you give it a list of classes and their dependencies (or in some cases just point it at a set of source files) and then ask it for a particular object, and it works out what other objects need to be created first. It can feel like magic, but underneath all it's doing is creating some objects and passing them to each other's constructors.